# Usage of Comparable Interface with generic static method in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparable

How to use Comparable interface with generic static method?

Suppose lets say I have:

```
**public static <T extends Comparable<T>>int larger(T[] array,T element)**
```

Why should I extend an Interface with T here instead of using implements?

Please Help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Java generics, you should use `extends` even to interfaces, there's no such thing as `impelements` in bounded types.